# Import .xlsx to oracle sql developer error

Tags: sql, oracle, import

I am exporting a .xlsx file with 1,000,000 rows to sql developer using the 'Import Data' function. However, I get the error:

```
Error during handleEvent on action 'Import Data... ' (id=998).
None of the attached controllers handled the action. -  oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction$ControllerDelegatingController@6eb6ea5e[oracle.dbt ools.raptor.controls.sqldialog.ObjectACtionController]
```

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: save your .xlsx file as a .txt file and use SQL Loader

Comment: Your title says that you are importing but your problem says that you are exporting.  I assume that you mean to say that you are importing a .xlsx file using SQL Developer.  Are you using the most recent version of SQL Developer?  Is this a one-time load or an ongoing process?

Comment: Hi - yes, I am importing a .xlsx file using SQL Developer. I am using the most recent of SQL Developer and it's an ongoing process (i'll have to do it ~20 times)

Answer (score 1):

Try using .xls file instead of .xlsx file. It should work fine.